# populating TextWatcher from database (sqlite)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to fetch data from database on each integer type and set Text to two other `EditText` but when I press any key App crashed

**Here is my try :**

```
    protected final TextWatcher BarCodeWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getTestData(s.toString());

        Log.e("Hello :",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Item_Name")));
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {

            String itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Item_Name"));
            itemNameEdit.setText(itemName);
            String unitPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Sale_Price"));
            unitPriceEdit.setText(unitPrice);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```

**Logcat: **

```
Process: com.example.fani.project, PID: 29441
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
```

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Please Check now or I should post complete Logcat?

Comment: okay. Please call this Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getTestData(s.toString()); in oncreate()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611534/sqlitedatabase-rawqueryjava-lang-string-java-lang-string-on-a-null-object

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have already called it in Oncreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have done it this way:

```
 protected final TextWatcher barcodeWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (s.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter BarCode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            itemNameEdit.setText("");
            unitPriceEdit.setText("");
        } else {

            mDbHelper.open();
            Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getItemNamePriceWithBarCode(s.toString());
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {

                itemNameEdit.setText("");
                unitPriceEdit.setText("");
            } else {
                String itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Item_Name"));
                itemNameEdit.setText(itemName);
                String unitPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Sale_Price"));
                unitPriceEdit.setText(unitPrice);
                itemID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_Item_ID"));
            }
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```